# Alpha Vantage API with python | How can I iterate through a list to produce multiple plots

Tags: python, pandas, alpha-vantage

#### I'm new to programming and I'm working with the Alpha_Vantage API. I created a list of stock symbols. I want to iterate through the list and produce a plot for each of the stocks on the list. The "symbol=" parameter is where I want to insert my list. So far I've only been able to produce multiple plots of the same stock. The code I've tried is listed below.

```
tickers = ['PENN', 'MGM', 'DKNG', 'TSLA']

data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(tickers[i]  ,interval='1min', outputsize='full')


for i in range(len(tickers)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data['4. close'])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I used this and it worked.

```
for ticker in tickers:
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(ticker ,interval='1min', outputsize='compact')
    plt.plot(data['4. close'])
    plt.show()
```